# google chrome turns down new volume on a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, audio

In google chrome, Whenever i'm listening to youtube on a tab and I open up a new tab it dampens the volume, but only when im searching on google. I don't have any idea whats up with it, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

you may have a sound enhancer software like Dolby Enhanced Audio, this happens to me too. it only enchances the sound when a media tab/webpage is open.

Check of you have Dolby or Beats installed, open the software and monitor as you switch webpages